# How to send text from Windows Phone 8.1 via HttpWebRequest / POST?

Tags: post, text, httpwebrequest, runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a web service that expects (unicode `UTF-8 encoded`) text data as an `HTTP POST` message.
I'd like to use it from a `Windows Phone 8.1 runtime client`.
I created the client, but it does not invoke the `web URI`.

Here's the code I use on the client:

Can anyone tell what am I missing?

Thanks,
B

```
{
...
    SendText("http://192.168.1.107:58709/UploadText.aspx"); // The IP belongs to the web server, port is correct. I can invoke it from a browser.
...
}


string StringToSend = "This is a test string uploaded via HTTP POST from WP8";

private void SendText(string Url)
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(UploadText_GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
}

public void UploadText_GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
    byte[] postDataAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSend);
    postStream.Write(postDataAsBytes, 0, postDataAsBytes.Length);
    postStream.Flush();
    // postStream.Close();  // Close is not available in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime project.
    // request.ContentLength = postDataAsBytes.ToString();  // request.ContentLength is not available in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime project.
    request.Headers["Content-length"] = postDataAsBytes.ToString();
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
}
```

Comment: Well, I got this far:

Comment: I think there is an emulator connectivity problem.
I followed this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/738846/How-to-Solve-issues-of-Internet-not-working-with-w) to fix Hyper-V connectivity settings.
Now the emulator can see the Internet.
However, the emulator can't access the development web server on the host: I start the test web site created in VStudio, set a breakpoint in it. When I access it from IE on the host, I hit the breakpoint. When I try to reach it from the emulator, I do not hit the breakpoint and do not get the response from the test webpage...

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems the code was correct...

Problem was, that the phone emulator could not connect to the development server (IIS Express). I searched the web over, tried a number of solutions, but I could not make it happen. In the meantime I trashed my wifi connection, had to remove and reinstall Hyper-V to make it work again.

The workaround was to publish the test web app to the local IIS (make sure it is the Debug version that is published) then attach to it from the debugger, call from WP8.1 emulator - and it works.